# Nested commands

Tags: macros

I defined a command that replaces certain characters inside a given string:

```
\newcommand{\spacesToHyphen}[1]{\convertchar{#1}{ }{-}}
```

This command works as intended with a string like this and replaces all spaces with hyphens:

```
\spacesToHyphen{Virtual Reality}
```

What I try to achieve is to pass an acronym definition to my command like this:

```
\spacesToHyphen{\ac{VR}}
```

Unfortunately, this command fails. How can I achieve nested commands like these in LaTeX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several problems.  The first argument to `\convertchar` must already be fully expanded, rather than a provided macro.  So, for example, the following would work: `\def\myphrase{Virtual Reality}
\expandafter\spacesToHyphen\expandafter{\myphrase}`.  Secondly however, in your use case, the provided macro `\ac`, if I recall, is not an expandable macro.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with this workaround instead of using the above command to replace the spaces:
`Virtual-Reality(\acs{VR})\acused{VR}`